Calculating or approximating the log-probability density for hypoexponential distribution (i.e. distribution of sum of exponential rvs)
If $\tau_i \overset{\text{independent}}{\sim}
 \exp(\lambda_i)$, for $i=1,2,3, \dotsc,n$, where $\lambda_i\neq \lambda_j, \forall i\neq j$ then:
$$
t:=\sum_{i=1}^n \tau_i \sim \text{Hypoexponential}(\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \dotsc,\lambda_n\}).
$$
The hypoexponential distribution pdf has this form:
$$
p(t|\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \dotsc,\lambda_n\}) := \sum_{i=1}^n \mathcal{l}_i(0) \lambda_i \exp(-\lambda_i t),
$$
where
$$
\mathcal{l}_i(0):=\prod_{j=1 \\ j \neq i}^{n} \frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_j-\lambda_i},
$$
are known as the Lagrange polynomials.
I would like to calculate the log-probability density or a good approximation of this model in an efficient manner. Note: this question is related to this one, but it is more general, and I think others would benefit from an answer.
Note 1: trying to stabilise exact calculation. I am limited by the fact that finding a stable form for the log-probability density is tricky. The difficulty is that the $\mathcal{l}_i(0)$ terms can grow large in absolute value -- the terms can be positive and negative and they sort of need to cancel one another out in order to ensure that you get reasonable probabilities.
To handle this so far, I have tried doing everything on the log-absolute scale. This means I calculate:
$$
\mathcal{L}_i:=\log \left[|\mathcal{l}_i(0) \lambda_i \exp(-\lambda_i t)|\right] = \log(\lambda_i) -\lambda_i t + \sum_{j=1}^{n} \left( \mathbf{1}_{j \neq i} \left( \log(\lambda_j) - \log(|\lambda_j - \lambda_i|) \right) \right).
$$
I then determine the sign of $\mathcal{L}$ by calculating it using this 'stable' form of the Lagrange polynomials. If then have $\mathcal{L}:=\{\mathcal{L}_1,\mathcal{L}_2,...,\mathcal{L}_n\}$ and $\text{sign}(\mathcal{L}):=\{\text{sign}(\mathcal{L}_1),\text{sign}(\mathcal{L}_2),...,\text{sign}(\mathcal{L}_n)\}$. I then do a sort of log-sum-exp trick:
$$
\text{val} := \max(\text{sign}(\mathcal{L}) \cdot \mathcal{L}),
$$
then
$$
\text{sumExpVal}:=\sum\left(\exp(\mathcal{L} - \text{val}) \cdot \text{sign}(\mathcal{L})\right),
$$
and finally this yields the log of the probability:
$$
\log p(t|\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \dotsc,\lambda_n\}) = \text{val} + \log(|\text{sumExpVal}|).
$$
In R, I can write functions to do this:
omega <- function(j, n, lambdas) {
  a <- 1.0
  for (m in 1:n) {
    if (m != j) {
      a <- a * 1 / (lambdas[j] - lambdas[m])
    }
  }
  return(a)
}

langrange_stable <- function(i, n, lambdas) {
  sum_term <- 0.0
  for (m in 1:n) {
    sum_term <- sum_term + omega(m, n, lambdas) / lambdas[m]
  }
  result <- omega(i, n, lambdas) / lambdas[n] * 1 / sum_term
  return(result)
}

L_i <- function(t, i, lambdas) {
  first_term <- log(lambdas[i]) - lambdas[i] * t
  second_term <- 0
  for(j in seq_along(lambdas))
    second_term <- second_term + if_else(j != i, log(lambdas[j]) - 
                     log(abs(lambdas[j] - lambdas[i])), 0)
  first_term + second_term
}

log_probability <- function(t, lambdas) {
  n <- length(lambdas)
  L_is <- vector(length = n)
  multipliers <- vector(length = n)
  for(i in seq_along(L_is)) {
    L_is[i] <- L_i(t, i, lambdas)
    multipliers[i] <- langrange_stable(i, n, lambdas) 
    # only need l_i(0) for sign determination
  }
  sign_L <- sign(multipliers)
  val <- max(sign_L * L_is)
  sum_exp_val <- sum(exp(L_is - val) * sign_L)
  val + log(abs(sum_exp_val))
}

I can then create some $\lambda$ values and compare the simulated distribution for a sum of exponentially distributed rvs with the log-probability derived from the above.
rhypoexponential <- function(n_replicates, lambdas) {
  ts <- vector(length = n_replicates)
  for(i in seq_along(ts)) {
    
    tau_sum <- 0
    for(j in seq_along(lambdas))
      tau_sum <- tau_sum + rexp(1, rate=lambdas[j])
    
    ts[i] <- tau_sum
  }
  ts
}

plot_log_pdf <- function(ts_to_eval, lambdas) {
  log_pdfs <- vector(length = length(ts_to_eval))
  for(i in seq_along(log_pdfs))
    log_pdfs[i] <- log_probability(ts_to_eval[i], lambdas)
  plot(ts_to_eval, log_pdfs)
}

I then try this with a $\lambda$ vector of length 10.
lambdas <- runif(10, 0, 20)
ts <- rhypoexponential(1000, lambdas)
ggplot2::qplot(ts)

which produces this:

The corresponding log-pdf plot also looks reasonable:
ts_to_eval <- seq(1, 20, 1)
plot_log_pdf(ts_to_eval, lambdas)


With a longer lambda vector, here of length 50, the above approach runs and outputs -Inf for even moderately large $t$, presumably due to numerical underflow -- I think in calculating the $\text{sumExpVal}$ term. The approach above is also extremely slow due to the various order $n^2$ calculations involved in calculating terms:
lambdas <- runif(50, 0, 100)
ts <- rhypoexponential(1000, lambdas)
ggplot2::qplot(ts)
plot_log_pdf(ts_to_eval, lambdas)



Note 2: gamma approximation. It is straightforward to approximate the Hypoexponential distribution by matching its first two moments using a gamma distribution. But this approximation is often bad.
The mean of a Hypoexponential random variable is:
$$
\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\lambda_i}.
$$
Its variance is:
$$
\sigma^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\lambda_i^2}.
$$
and this equates to a gamma (shape, rate parameterisation) of the form: $\text{gamma}(\mu^2/\sigma^2,\mu/\sigma)$.
Across a range of $\lambda$ the approximation is fairly poor, for example, the below:
rgamma_mu_sigma <- function(n, lambdas) {
  mu <- sum(1/lambdas)
  sigma2 <- sum(1/lambdas^2)
  rgamma(n, mu^2/sigma2, mu/sigma2)
}

n <- 10000
lambdas <- c(0.3300521, 1.4280659, 3.7897867, 3.5342999, 2.5767548)
exact_ts <- rhypoexponential(n, lambdas)
gamma_ts <- rgamma_mu_sigma(n, lambdas)
tibble(exact=exact_ts, gamma=gamma_ts) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(exact, gamma)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=value)) +
  geom_density(aes(colour=name))



Does the R package sdprisk with the pdf function dhypoexp solve most of the numerical precision issues for you?  Also, if you could either give the specific lambda values or the random number seed to obtain the lambda values, that would help.  (I'm assuming from your previous questions that you need a solution using R.)

If you sort the $\lambda$ values from low to high, the sign of $l_i (0)$ is positive if $i$ is odd and negative if $i$ is even.  That would seem simpler that the process you're currently using.

A vectorized version of the hypoexponential PDF in R (also using Rmpfr):
library(Rmpfr)

dhypoexp <- function(x, lambdas, log = FALSE, prec = 128) {
  lambdas <- mpfr(lambdas, prec)
  x <- mpfr(x, prec)
  d <- outer(lambdas, lambdas, "-")
  m <- length(lambdas)
  n <- length(x)
  diag(d) <- 1
  logabsterms <- sum(log(lambdas)) - colSums(log(abs(d))) -
    matrix(rep(lambdas, n)*rep(x, each = m), m, n)
  out <- crossprod(exp(logabsterms), 1 - 2*colSums(d < 0)%%2)
  as.numeric(if (log) log(out) else out)
}

Example usage:
(seed <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, 1))
#> [1] 1239566757
set.seed(seed)

N <- 50
lambdas <- runif(N, 0, 100)

# generate 1e6 random hypoexponential variates
x <- colSums(matrix(rexp(1e6*N, lambdas), N))
(r <- range(x))
#> [1]  0.9018059 17.1974144
hist(x, 100, FALSE)
system.time(
  curve(dhypoexp(x, lambdas), r[1], r[2], col = "blue", add = TRUE)
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.20    0.00    0.21


Side note: this was updated from a previous version that used outer, which I found was very slow for mpfr objects:
x <- mpfr(runif(100), 128)
y <- mpfr(runif(100), 128)

bench::mark(
  outer = outer(x, y),
  repmult = matrix(rep(x, length(y))*rep(y, each = length(x)), length(x), length(y))
)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 outer          3.2s     3.2s     0.312     771MB     10.0
#> 2 repmult      32.2ms   41.5ms    22.3       721KB     18.6


+1 Much more compact and faster than my code.

Exponential distributions are scaled $\chi^2_2$ distributions, so you can also use techniques for linear combinations of $\chi^2$ distributions, which have been studied as the distribution of quadratic forms in Gaussians:

a saddlepoint approximation due to Kuonen (in the survey package) which is especially good for small tail probabilities or moderately large numbers of summands
inverting the characteristic function (the "Davies" method in the CompQuadForm package)
an infinite series of Beta functions (the "Farebrother" method in the CompQuadForm package)
approximate by a convolution of a few leading terms and the Gamma approximation to the remaining terms, which is especially good for very large numbers of summands or when you are given a matrix whose eigenvalues or singular values are the $\lambda$s rather than being given the $\lambda$s directly (see paper here or blog post here, or bigQF package)


I think the numeric stabilization for this particular probability density requires more numeric precision than what the default double precision can offer (even after the usually useful "log-sum-exp trick".  Here I use the Rmpfr library.
First define a function that will produce the pdf (or log(pdf)) given the hypoexponential parameters and a vector of values to calculate the pdf.
# Load library
  library(Rmpfr)

# Define function to produce the pdf values
  pdf <- function(t, lambda, logPDF=FALSE, maxBits=200) {
    # t is a vector of values to evaluate the pdf
    # lambda is a vector of the hypoexponential rates
    # maxBits is the number of binary bits for the high precision floating point numbers
    # The pdf values are output if logPDF=FALSE.  Otherwise the log of the pdf values are returned.
                                         
    n <- length(lambda)
    lambda0 <- mpfr(lambda, maxBits) # Convert to high precision floating point numbers
    
    # Calculate lagrange polynomials
    lagrange <- mpfr(rep(0, n), maxBits)
    for (i in 1:n) {
        product <- lambda0/(lambda0 - lambda0[i])
        product[i] <- mpfr(1, maxBits)  # This is the element that is inf in the above vector
        lagrange[i] <- prod(product)
    } 
   
    # Now calculate pdf values
    t0 <- mpfr(t, maxBits)
    total <- mpfr(rep(0, length(t)), maxBits)
    for (i in 1:length(t)) {
        total[i] <- sum(lambda0 * lagrange * exp(-lambda0*t0[i]))
    }
    
    # Return pdf or log(pdf) values
    if (logPDF) {
       asNumeric(log(total))
    } else {
       asNumeric(total)
    }
  }

Now for a specific example.
# Set lambda values
  n <- 30
  lambda <- c(1.61194, 4.18716, 3.48782, 6.66293, 3.07288, 8.31177, 
    4.93457, 6.6087, 20.4747, 2.47034, 1.54648, 6.67345, 3.94997, 3.54765, 
    2.65146, 4.54139, 5.62278, 1.57728, 7.04541, 9.54187, 6.49925, 2.14693, 
    6.00469, 1.20595, 6.44199, 8.14599, 4.01718, 3.32529, 3.51255, 7.0308)
  
# Mean and standard deviation of hypoexponential distribution
  m <- sum(1/lambda)
  stdev <- sqrt(sum(1/lambda^2))
  
# Plot pdf for values of t from 0 to m + 4*stdev
  par(ask=TRUE)
  t <- (m + 4*stdev)*c(1:100)/100
  d <- pdf(t, lambda)                               
  plot(t, d, type="l", xlab="t", ylab="Probability density", las=1, lwd=3)
  lines(c(0, m + 4*stdev), c(0, 0))


# Plot log(pdf) for values of t from 0 to m + 4*stdev
  t <- (m + 4*stdev)*c(1:100)/100
  d <- pdf(t, lambda, logPDF=TRUE)
  plot(t, d, type="l", xlab="t", ylab="Log of probability density", las=1, lwd=3)


